# Date Format to dd/MM/yyyy in TextBoxFor type date

Tags: html, date, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project that require to introduce dates to create many objects.

When I'm testing it on Chrome, there's no problem. The problem is when I'm running it on Firefox or Internet Explorer.

For Example, on Chrome I use this line (it works fine and display a datepicker):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateReception, new { style = "font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Light'; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: black;", id = "DateReception", type = "date", min = "2016-01-01", required = "true", @class = "col-sm-10" })
```

For other browsers, the datepicker doesn't display so I use this line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateReception, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { style = "font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Light'; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: black;", id = "DateReceptionOther", type = "date", required = "true", @class = "numbersOnly col-sm-10" })
```

The problem is that when it comes to validate the model and to pass it to the controller, this is not working... The browser expects me to set the date to the "MM/dd/yyy" format but I need the "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

For that, I added `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` on my html line just before and my model looks like:

```
[Display(Name = "Date de réception :")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DateReception { get; set; }
```

There's a picture of the error on my web page (25/12/2016 is not working while 12/12/2016 is)

[image: Example of the error]

Comment: Hope this post will help https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/08/html5-input-typedate-formatting-issues

Comment: I already tried it but problem is still here

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed this problem for my self.

This goes in the Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You found was put in the web.config the next

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture='auto' uiCulture='auto'/>
</system.web>
```

en-US: M/d/yyyy (e.g. mm/dd/yyyy)

en-GB: dd/MM/yyyy (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: It was like that before I changed from what I saw on the internet but didn't work